# multi label classification with bad performance in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, text-classification, multilabel-classification

I tried to do multi-label classification on tensorflow, but i got bad performance.

Input:[1,0,1, ...,0] (one-hot) and text content

```
    def lstm_cell():  
        return tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(self.config.hidden_dim, state_is_tuple=True)

    def gru_cell():
        return tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(self.config.hidden_dim)

    def dropout():
        if (self.config.rnn == 'lstm'):
            cell = lstm_cell()
        else:
            cell = gru_cell()
        return tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell, output_keep_prob=self.keep_prob)
```

model:
 embedding layer

```
   with tf.device('/cpu:0'):

        embedding = tf.get_variable('embedding', [self.config.vocab_size, self.config.embedding_dim])
        embedding_inputs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding, self.input_x)
```

bi-lstm

```
   with tf.name_scope("rnn"):
        cells = [dropout() for _ in range(self.config.num_layers)]
        rnn_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(cells, state_is_tuple=True)
        _outputs, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=rnn_cell, inputs=embedding_inputs, dtype=tf.float32)
        last = _outputs[:, -1, :]
```

active by relu

```
   with tf.name_scope("score"):

        fc = tf.layers.dense(last, self.config.hidden_dim, name='fc1')
        fc = tf.contrib.layers.dropout(fc, self.keep_prob)
        fc = tf.nn.relu(fc)

        self.logits = tf.layers.dense(fc, self.config.num_classes, name='fc2')
        self.y_pred_cls = tf.nn.sigmoid(self.logits, name='pred')
```

use sigmoid cross entropy

```
   with tf.name_scope("optimize"):

        cross_entropy = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=self.logits, labels=self.input_y)
        self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
        self.optim = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=self.config.learning_rate).minimize(self.loss)
```

calculate acc

```
    with tf.name_scope("accuracy"):

        threashold=0.5
        self.labels = tf.equal(self.input_y, 1)
        self.preds = tf.greater_equal(self.y_pred_cls,threashold)
        self.correct_num = tf.divide(tf.size(tf.where(tf.logical_not(tf.logical_xor(self.labels, self.preds)))),2)
        self.total_num = tf.size(self.input_y)
        self.correct_pred = tf.divide(tf.cast(self.correct_num, tf.float32),tf.cast(self.total_num, tf.float32))

        self.acc = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(self.correct_pred, tf.float32))
```

model predict [0,0,....0](all zero) on test data,
didn't belong any category.

what's wrong on my code or model design? thank.